# Passing data to controller using Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to write a link to a partial view on the same page. Everything works, except that I am not able to pass in the needed month parameter through my ajax.actionlink syntax. I've tried using the ViewDataDictionary, but to no avail. Also, RouteValueParameter was a thought I had, but I'm trying to pass a string, not an integer id.

Below is my code in the view, followed by the method in the controller:

```
<td>@Ajax.ActionLink("January", "ControllerMethod", new ViewDataDictionary{{"month", "January"}}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "view-month" })</td>



public ActionResult ViewMonths(string month)
    {
        //some code here
        return PartialView("ViewMonths", schedule);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `actionName` is the first parameter and should be `"ViewMonths"`, `controllerName` is the second parameter of `ActionLink` and should be the name of the controller class but without the word 'controller'. Change it and test it by putting a breakpoint inside the method.

Comment: I meant second and third :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this way

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link Text", "MyAction", "MyController", new { month = "January",  plum = "2", moreparams = "U can do this all day"}, new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "view-month" } )
```

Greatings